# How to connect multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I created this table with data from the database.
table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnO3B.jpg

I need all the rows with month May to be in 1 row
like this:

May 2019 |  | 3 | 3| 2|
etc.

My DB looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcgoy.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iigB3.jpg

So far I got this code

```
$tipsportsql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%b %Y') AS 'Monthyear', count(projekt) AS 'project' FROM zapasy WHERE projekt = '0' AND komentator1 = '$firstname $lastname' OR projekt = '0' AND komentator2 = '$firstname $lastname' GROUP BY Monthyear");

$slaviasql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%b %Y') AS 'Monthyear', count(projekt) AS 'project' FROM zapasy WHERE projekt = '1' AND komentator1 = '$firstname $lastname' OR projekt = '1' AND komentator2 = '$firstname $lastname' GROUP BY Monthyear");

$betsql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%b %Y') AS 'Monthyear', count(projekt) AS 'project' FROM zapasy WHERE projekt = '2' AND komentator1 = '$firstname $lastname' OR projekt = '2' AND komentator2 = '$firstname $lastname' GROUP BY Monthyear");
```

and this

```
<tbody>
        <?php while ($tip = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tipsportsql)) {?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?=$tip['Monthyear'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$tip['project']?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php } while ($tip = mysqli_fetch_assoc($slaviasql)) {?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?=$tip['Monthyear'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$tip['project']?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php }while ($tip = mysqli_fetch_assoc($betsql)) {?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?=$tip['Monthyear'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
            <?=$tip['project']?>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
```

I am thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want a query like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%b %Y') AS Monthyear, 
       SUM(projekt = 0) AS project_1,
       SUM(projekt = 1) AS project_2,
       SUM(projekt = 2) AS project_3
FROM zapasy
WHERE CONCAT(?, ?) IN (komentator1, komentator2)
GROUP BY Monthyear;
```

Note in particular the parameter placeholders.  You need to learn how to use parameters so your queries are not vulnerable to unexpected syntax errors and SQL injection attacks.